# How to use ng-repeat with an ajax request with DataTables?

Tags: ajax, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, datatables

Let's say I'd like to load a dataTable dynamically, but instead of using normal ajax function within datatable, I'd like to load it through Angular, use ng-repeat to generate the tr elements and then apply DataTables. Would that be possible? In broad terms, how could I do that?

I've got the ajax/ng-repeat working already like this:

```
angular.module('myApp',  ['ngResource', 'ui.bootstrap'])
.factory('ProjectsService', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/customers');
}])
.controller('AdminCustomersCtrl', ['ProjectsService', '$scope', function(ProjectsService, $scope) {
    $scope.projects = ProjectsService.query();

}]);
```

The reason I'd like to do this is that all elements (data in the table) would be binded, so whenever the user edit an entry in the table, the change would be acknowledged immediately (visually) and also saved to the REST server. Each entry in the table would correspond to a mongo db document. So if anyone has any ideas of how to achieve this differently, I'd love suggestions.